# Visual Studio : expand the find usages results by default

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio (2010), when finding usages of a certain class or method, the find results dialog appears with the usages.

Is there a way to expand the results by default, so I won't need to click on the 'Expand All' button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use the ReSharper addon there is an option to "Expand search results tree by default". I've searched Google and can't find a built in option.

Choose `Resharper| Options`, then under `Environment | Search & Navigation`:

[image: Expand search in Options]

Answer (score 0):

This makes life a little bit better
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/04/03/did-you-know-you-can-use-to-expand-all-and-to-collapse-all-in-the-toolbox-186.aspx

Comment: That link talks about the Toolbox; the question is about the Find Results dialog.

Comment: I am using it for Find Results.  The trick applies to all Tree like view on Windows.  + and - keys works too.  Have you tried before comment or it does not work for you?

Comment: This works in typical grids (pressing * or /), but not in the Find Results when ReSharper is installed. In this case, typing anything will start filtering the results themselves (based on the characters typed), and activates a textbox to do this.